# What artifacts should be created during the lifecycle of a project?

Tags: documentation, enterprise, frameworks

Looking at the lifecycle of a project, is there a industry standard (not specific to only project management) or a set of best practices of the artifacts that should be created as part of a project?

I am looking at this from the perspective of key stakeholders e.g. business analysts, architects, project managers, operations, support, etc.

For example, from an architectural perspective, this could include conceptual design, high level designs, detailed designs as well as technical designs such as infrastructure, networks, software and the like. These would move through the stages of inception, feasibility, build, deploy and support.

I am hoping to create a checklist of sorts. Since the organization i work is still in the infancy stages from a maturity perspective (although it is an entity that has been around 20 years), there isn't either the skill, the ownership or incentive, i am taking to take this on myself.

As for my role, i sit across the enterprise architecture practice and am looking at ways to elevate core practices that drive standards and improved practices & processes.

**EDIT**

To add to Tobias' question, this is for the purposes of the transportation vertical

Comment: There are a lot of standards out there, depending on national law, industry, profession, and customer. E.g. PMBOK for PM or DO-178 for aerospace SW development. Could you add those details?

Comment: @Tobias - Thanks Tobias. I have added the details for the industry this is relevant to. Do these standards encompass stakeholders such as business analysts, architects, etc?

Comment: The PMBOK is not for technical documents but for PM artifacts. The DO-178 describes the development process and the required artifacts. I guess most standards describe artifacts but not the responsibility within the organization to create them. Nevertheless, it shouldn't be so hard to perform a matching, for e.g. Requirements Management Plan, System Architecture or Test Procedure...

Comment: @Tobias - Thanks Tobias. I am attempting to look for something that is cross functional i.e. across project management, architecture, business analysis, etc. Is there a standard or set of practices that cover these?

Comment: Have a look on the V-Modell, I posted in my answer. It is cross functional and tries to cover all system engineering aspects incl. PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing from transportation vertical industry, but regarding something industry independent and applicable for HW, SW, and embedded systems, the **V-Model** could be something to start with: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model.

Here is a link to the complete description in English: ftp://ftp.heise.de/pub/ix/ix_listings/projektmanagement/vmodell/V-Modell-XT-Gesamt-Englisch-V1.3.pdf

Be aware that as more general you are searching, as more general will be the described processes or artifacts. If you continue to focus, you'll find more concrete answers.

E.g. Regarding software development, you'll find really nice templates when you look for MIL-STD 498 (which is outdated).

Comment: Do you have any information about the use of v-models in architecture? The examples i have come across are predominantly software development led as well as testing.

Comment: Sorry, nothing I know about. It's main propose is for systems and software engineering. But I would bet the principles can be adopted to all engineering related professions.

Comment: Thanks Tobias. When i meant architecture, i was referring to enterprise and solution architecture.

Comment: Within the above linked document it is statet, that the V-Model is independent of the organizational structure due to the introduction of roles. I would say, you have to tailor the V-Model to your requirements / projects. Doing this, you'll find some roles more important than others. Finally you might be able to derive an enterprise architecture supporting the *surving* roles best.

Comment: http://v-modell.iabg.de/dmdocuments/V-Modell-XT-Gesamt-Englisch-V1.3.pdf : this link is not valid anymore. Can you please share an updated one? Secondly, what are the artefacts expected as an output in each phase?

Comment: @dirai Link is updated. Unfortunately, it seems the linked document is missing the artefacts. I‘ll try to find the complete English document online but was not yet successful.